# Delicate cancelation of step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there a way to cancel a state machine execution without fully exiting the step functions? Our state machine has a failure path that does a lot of cleanup which would be missed if the execution is canceled mid workflow.

I am stumped and not sure if anyone else has ever come across a solution to this?

/MN

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I have run into a similar use case.  I wish I could just do it all in my state machine, but so far I have not found that capability.  What I implemented instead was to have a Lambda function that is triggered by an EventBridge rule.  I use an EventBridge rule with:

```
EventPattern:
  source:
    - aws.states
  detail-type:
    - Step Functions Execution Status Change
  detail:
    status:
      - SUCCEEDED
      - FAILED
      - ABORTED
      - TIMED_OUT
```

Then in my Lambda function I can inspect the event and the execution history to perform my cleanup.

Comment: That's clever, thanks for chiming in! Never thought about it that way

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire state machine in a parallel state task but only have the one branch - your main path. You can then attach a catch for "States.All" and point that to your cleanup lambda tasks.

But if you mean cancel as in actively use the CLI or an SDK to cancel a state machine execution with `stop execution` Then there isn't a way to do so inside the states  machine. However. If you use the SDK to send the call from inside a lambda you could call your clean up functionality after that (even call the same lambdas/services your step function uses) and get most of what you probably need out of `describe execution` CLI/SDK command

Comment: Yeah was thinking that there could be some sort of lambda which would cleanup after but was then wondering If I would lose context to the state machine ticket once the CLI stops the execution. 


Was thinking another option is to move the cleanup functionality to a smaller state machine that chains off the first but not entirely sure if that would work.

Comment: You would loose the context, but you can capture most of that with `describe_execution`